Visual studio code : Unable to enable Git Base extension
I'm connecting remote server via SSH I'm not able to see my changes in source control
This extension is disabled in this workspace because it is defined to run in the Remote Extension Host. Please install the extension in 'SSH: 10.7.30.230' to enable
enter image description here
Unable to see my changes in vscode it showing like this :
"Scanning folder for Git repositories"

Had same issue I know some time has passed but maybe helps someone else
this did the trick
Connect via ssh directly, run this:
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/
rm -rf ~/.vscode-remote/

And afterwards reconnect through vscode and redownload all
Based it on this
VScode SSH extension keeps disconnecting after moving to a new location
